# Python Array: Continuous Field

Tags: python, arrays, image, grouping, cluster-analysis

I am trying to group objects in an array where positive values above, below, left and right would indicate a common group but diagonal would not. See example below.

```
input = [
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
]

output = [
 [0,a,a,a,0,0,0],
 [0,a,a,a,0,0,0],
 [0,0,a,a,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,b,b,0],
 [0,c,c,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,c,c,0,0,d],
]
```

At the moment my solution is to loop through the array testing each value against the values alongside. Owing to the size of the arrays ~2500x~1400, the solution is running very slowly.

Does anyone know of any libraries that are optimised for this or any ideas on the best way to accomplish this, please?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: definitely `numpy` for that task, how to group by idk...

Comment: If you run a lot of loops, it may be worth looking into numba. It can help speed up your loops by just-in-time compiling your code into machine-code.

Comment: thank you, @sunnytown - I will look into it.

Comment: Looks like a task for `skimage.measure.label` https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label with `1-connectivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @Max111. That was exactly what I was after.

```
from skimage.measure import label

input = np.array([
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
])

output = label(input, connectivity=1)
```